# Вывести элементы массива в обратном порядке. Всплывает ошибка ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, массивы

Пример кода:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] text = {"This", "is", "a", "test"};
    for (int i = text.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = text[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            System.out.println(text[i].charAt(j));
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Должно быть `int i = text.length - 1;`, так как последний индекс в массиве - "length - 1"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Один из быстрых вариантов:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("This", "is", "a", "test");
    Collections.reverse(list);
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Что касается ошибки вашего кода, вы начинали обход массива с 4 индекса, а нодо было указать text.length - 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] text = {"This", "is", "a", "test"};
    for (int i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = text[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            System.out.print(text[i].charAt(j));
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

но лучше такой вариант:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] text = {"This", "is", "a", "test"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(sortArray(text)));
}

public static String[] sortArray(String[] array) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, array.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> array[array.length - i])
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: А чем лучше второй вариант? Работает он ощутимо медленнее, выглядит сложнее (хотя это субъективно, да). То что вывод на экран отличается от оного в коде автора - возможно, не сильно важно.

Answer (score 0):

`text.length` - возвращает длину массива, т. е. в данном случае `4`. Индексы в массиве начинаются с `0`, т. е. последний элемент `3`. Поэтому добавляем `-1`, примерно так:

```java
String[] text = {"This", "is", "a", "test"};

// вывод массива строк
// в обратном порядке
IntStream.range(0, text.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> text[text.length - 1 - i])
        .forEach(System.out::println);
// test
// a
// is
// This
```